# writing to .xlsm file from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, macros, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

Here's the code I can use to write my pandas to .xlsx file

```
result_top5.to_excel('Top5NS_Report.xlsx',index = None)
```

It works perfectly.

But when I do the same by changing the extension to .xlsm, I get an error while trying to open the file, which says that the file extension is not valid.

What should my approach be?

I looked at the documentation given here
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html
but that confused me even more.

Answer (score 1):

The first question you should ask yourself is "does this file need macro, and if yes are the macro in the ram workbook?"

Secondly I see in the doc that you posted that the method used to write a xlsm file is "workbook" not "to_excel". Beware to use the right method!

Besides it seems that the "workbook" method is used to create a workbook object in which you will put your data before saving it to disc. "to_excell" is a method that does not seem to belong to the same class. maybe your data object has a different method to write to xlsm format.

finally you should verify that when you try to open the file you do it either from excell by specifying you want to open a xlsm file, or from your local file browser in which the file extension should be recognised.